# Move the externally loaded content of a MovieClip to another MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

I load an image into a MovieClip. At a second time I want to move this image to another MovieClip. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, that's possible.

just re-parent the image using removeChild() and addChild():

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new ULRRequest("pathToImage.jpg"));

movieclip1.addChild(loader);

// sometime later ...
movieclip1.removeChild(loader);  // optional
movieclip2.addChild(loader);
```

voilà ...

Comment: there is no need for calling removeChild before adding your DisplayObject in an other container

Comment: there's not? haven't tried it without the "remove". but removing it up front isn't wrong either - but optional as it seems ;)